# How would you order by two columns in MYSQL Database?

Tags: php

I have a complex problem that I have been working on for a while. I don't even know if this is possible to do.This is an iOS app where users can reorder rows in the tableview and it updates the database (ordering02) with the temporary indexpath.row.

---

Columns to order by:

- ordering01 : Products are ordered 1..2..3... and so on
- ordering02 : When product is moved to a new position (indexPath.row) in the app this temporarily holds the new position in the mysql database until the user saves changes. Once the user saves changes that position is then saved into ordering01.

---

What I am trying to do is display the unsaved product order in the app (tableView). To do this I will need to sort by both ordering01 & ordering02. The complicated part is that I need the query to check if ordering02 exists. If ordering02 exists then that's the column that is used but if it doesn't exist then the column used is ordering01.

---

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE status = '1' ORDER BY [Check if ordering 02 exists, if it does use ordering 02 if not use ordering01] "); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql01)){ 

}
```

Does this Make sense and is it even possible?

Comment: I would write PHP `if/else` statements and independent `mysql_query` statements.

Comment: Can you write if/else statements inside the query?

Comment: How does the query, which runs at the database, access `ordering01` and `ordering02`? Also, why try to complicate a query statement? The answer is yes, you can write `IF condition THEN statements; ELSEIF condition THEN statements; ELSE statements; END IF;

Comment: Right now all I have is ORDER BY ordering01 ASC... I don't know how I would implement the ordering02  check inside the query ORDER BY? Unless there's a way I could combine 2 separate queries and order them together.

Comment: Ok Im looking up IF ELSE inside the query. Im on the right track now

Comment: In PHP write `if (ordering02) mysql_query(...) else mysql_query(...)` There is no need to put IF/ELSE in the SQL. Your goal should be to write the simplest, cleanest, fastest SQL and do the upfront logic before hitting the database.

Comment: The thing that Im confused by is how would I check if (ordering02) exists if I do it before I run the query? I appreciate your help btw

Comment: Edit your question and provide more context. Is `ordering02` a database column or a user-selected item?

Comment: Ordering02 is a database column...

Comment: So Im thinking about it and its not even possible I don't think. I want to order 1 query by ordering01 & ordering02. I want the query to use ordering02 if it has a value and ordering01 if ordering02 doesn't have a value.

Comment: Do you want to do the sort row by row based upon each row's ordering02 column? The other option to sort on ordering02 if any row has a value. No matter which method, neither is a good design objective. Review database table normalization first. Also, consider the impact if the column is empty versus has a value. What is the final objective (answer that in your head for yourself).

Comment: `Once the user saves changes that position is then saved into ordering01` - Why not just store the new positions live with ajax? If the list of products is long people will tend to forget to click the save button....

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score -2):

For the temporary storage, why not use arrays, until the user clicks the save, then take from the array and insert into your table.

The best way to merge the two tables, is using the "JOINS" command in your SQL code and checking if the table exists, PHP offers a call method called "exists()", so you would first call the name of the table (ordering02) inside your if statement.

So you get:

```
$con = mysqli_connect(...);
$tblName = "ordering02";

If (exists($tblName)){
    # Perform action
}else{
    # table doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: ^ `exists` is not even an known `PHP` function